# DataFrame object Statmodels

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to create a linear regression with statsmodels. I've looked at a few articles and I think I'm almost there. I'd rather not have to type in each rows values as I'll have thousands of values (https://datatofish.com/statsmodels-linear-regression/) this article says to do that. I'm trying to pull from a csv file and use that instead. Here's my code but I'm getting the following error: df = DataFrame(DataFrame.columns) Type Error: 'DataFrame' object is not callable.

Here's the entire code. Basically want to run this regression and get a summary similar to what I'd get in R or Excel for all variables. I've input 2 for testing but I'll have about 20 variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Import the data
DataFrame = pd.read_csv("NBA.csv")

df = DataFrame(DataFrame.columns)

X = df[['A_OFFRTG','H_OFFRTG']]
Y = df['Margin']

X = sm.add_constant(X) # adding a constant

model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)

print_model = model.summary()
print(print_model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to be honest I am myself not sure what exactly are you doing with that line.

You can just change two lines and it should work all fine. Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Import the data
df = pd.read_csv("NBA.csv")

X = df[['A_OFFRTG','H_OFFRTG']]
Y = df['Margin']

X = sm.add_constant(X) # adding a constant

model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)

print_model = model.summary()
print(print_model)
```

I hope this works for you Ben.

Comment: Thank you! This is giving me a much lower R squared value than I get when I run the same regression in Excel. Any ideas on why? I've been setting the constant to 0 for this model in Excel

Comment: I really don't think you need to do that in excel. Excel's toolbox for regression assumes the constant if I remember correctly.

Btw, if this worked for you, could you accept it as the answer?